# Reference Request: Quasi-Coherent Sheaves, Picard Group, etc.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

I'm a rookie in algebraic geometry, trying to learn. Recently I noticed that I really don't understand the following topics very well. I am asking you if there is comprehensive references (one maybe with examples) to help me get comfortable and grasp these ideas:

- Quasi-Coherent Sheaves, Coherent Sheaves, etc.
- Construction of Quasi-Coherent Sheaves on a Projective Variety
- Invertible Sheaves I: Specifically the Sheaf $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m)$.
- Weil and Cartier Divisors
- Invertible Sheaves II: Picard Group $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$.
- Proof of Bezout's Theorem using Divisors

I've read more or less all of the above from *Kempf's Algebraic Varieties* multiple times. Truth is although I can read through it, I get lost in all the abstraction, losing sight of what is the core of the discussion. Every time I read those chapters, I think this time I got it. But then I encounter a problem related to one of these, and realize I don't exactly know what I'm doing. I have no insight...

To get you a feeling of how bad the situation is and how great is my confusion, the other day I was trying to solve a problem dealing with sheaves $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n)$. At one point I argued (shamefully) that "Since $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n)$ is quasi-coherent but not coherent, blah blah blah"... Not only $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n)$ is coherent it is actually rank one by definition! It was right there and then that I told myself "OK, if you are making such a trivial mistake, then you have a serious issue."

I looked up Hartshorne, Shafarevich (II) and Ravi Vakil's notes other than Kempf. One thing these sources all have in common is that they describe these ideas on a scheme. I don't really know about schemes (I know the definition, and I can read through them if I have to. But that is again an extra layer of abstraction...)

Comment: Schemes are good; anyway, have you seen Gathmann's notes? Those might help. There's also Mumford's _Algebraic Geometry I: Complex Projective Varieties_ (not the Red Book).

Comment: No I haven't thank you I will take a look.

Comment: Btw I have nothing against schemes, I'd love to learn about them and that's the plan. All in good time.

Comment: I was wondering whether you get the book you want or not. I have trouble in understanding all these topics too. I get lost in the abstract text and really want to get the motivation behind it.

Comment: @LukeChen The honest answer is I gave up. I realized I'm going to get nowhere without getting comfortable with schemes. So I committed to Vakil's notes (which is the best imo). It's been a while since I did any algebraic geometry, but how I managed to get comfortable with these ideas was just pause every few pages and try to simplify the abstraction for myself via making up simple examples and looking at them. That's really the only way. There is a reason AG is notorious for being inaccessible.